# How can I debug a lack of IO counts printed in Perl DBI's db_error_handler from a Sybase query?

Tags: perl, statistics, dbi, sap-ase

I'm having a fairly strange problem.

It's a bit of an X-Y problem, so I will first describe "X".

**Question X: How can I debug DBI internals using Perl?**

More specifically, the calls to DBI's db_error_handler. Some of the SQL server callback output is printed (Query plans) 100% of the time, but some (Actual IOs) is ONLY printed when the query returns zero rows (with `set statistics io on`).

---

**Ultimate problem Y I'm trying to address:**

For some reason, my Perl script prints query plans **but not actual IOs spent** when executing Sybase queries when the query returns a result set; BUT print both query plans AND actual IOs spent when the SAME query returns zero rows.

I have a script that, in essence, does this:

```
sub DoSql { # Sql execution wrapper
    my ($dbh, $sql) = @_;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
}

# Set up DB connection, with debug printing turned on
my $dbh = CreateDBH(); # Uses DBI and creates Sybase database handle DBI object
$dbh->DoSql("set statistics io on");
$dbh->DoSql("set showplan on");
# Print output from DBH callback
$dbh->{_db_error_handler} = sub { PrettyPrintSybaseDebug($_[6]); } 

$dbh->DoSql("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=100"); # 1 row returned
$dbh->DoSql("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=987654321"); # zero rows
```

When executing this script, the first query prints the following Sybase output from db_error_handler:

```
QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).
    STEP 1
        The type of query is SELECT.
         .....
Total estimated I/O cost for statement 1 (at line 1): 80.
```

**BUT the second query prints the following Sybase output (see the last 3 lines added):**

```
QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).
    STEP 1
        The type of query is SELECT.
         .....
Total estimated I/O cost for statement 1 (at line 1): 80.

Table: MyTable scan count 1, logical reads: (regular=3 apf=0 total=3), ...
Total actual I/O cost for this command: 6.
Total writes for this command: 0
```

Please note that when I execute these queries in raw `isql`, BOTH of them, as expected, print both the plan AND the scan counts per table and actual IOs. Both queries run fine and produce expected results sets (1 row and 0 rows respectively)

What am I doing wrong and how can I debug this? Unfortunately, `perl -d` doesn't help me, since I can only debug outside `$sth->execute();` call and inside the callback.

If it matters, my environment is:

- Perl 5.8.0
- Solaris 10
- Sybase ASE 12.5
- DBI version is 1.37

Comment: @bohica - DBD::Sybase 1.00.

Answer (score 2):

Using DBI trace information can show some more debug info for you: export DBI_TRACE=LEVEL where LEVEL from 1 to 15